# How to setup Swagger with Spring Boot Camel for REST messaging

Tags: spring-boot, rest, apache-camel, swagger

I'm following Swagger Java [example](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/others/swagger-java.html), but can't make it work with Spring Boot Camel.

I'm running Spring Boot Camel 3.4.0, and have next dependencies in `pom.xml`:

```
<!-- Spring Boot -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Camel -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-stream-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- REST -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-rest-starter</artifactId>
      </dependency>
       <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
         <artifactId>camel-servlet-starter</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
         <artifactId>camel-jackson-starter</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
         <artifactId>camel-jaxb-starter</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
         <artifactId>camel-netty-http-starter</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
         <artifactId>camel-http-starter</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
         <artifactId>camel-jetty-starter</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
         <artifactId>camel-undertow-starter</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <!--<dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
         <artifactId>camel-rest-swagger-starter</artifactId>
      </dependency>-->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
         <artifactId>camel-swagger-java</artifactId>
         <version>3.4.0</version>
      </dependency>
```

My `Router.java` is next:

```
String listenAddress = "192.168.0.100";
        int listenPort = 8080;

        restConfiguration()
                .component("netty-http")
                .scheme("http")
                .host(listenAddress)
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto)
                .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true")
                .port(listenPort)
                .contextPath("/")
                // add swagger api-doc out of the box
                .apiContextPath("/api-doc")
                .apiProperty("api.title", "User API").apiProperty("api.version", "1.2.3")
                // and enable CORS
                .apiProperty("cors", "true");

        // this user REST service is json only
        rest("/user").description("User rest service")
            .consumes("application/json").produces("application/json")
            .get("/{id}").description("Find user by id").outType(User.class)
                .param().name("id").type(path).description("The id of the user to get").dataType("int").endParam()
                .log("Swagger REST header id: ${header.id}");
```

If trying to GET http://192.168.0.100:8080/api-doc I'm getting 404.

This route above should print log in Camel terminal when using REST GET with http://192.168.0.100:8080/user/123 or am I wrong? Can't see what's missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context path by default is set to `/camel/`, which means if rest of your configuration is correct, you should be able to see your api-docs at `http://192.168.0.100:8080/camel/api-doc`

To override it, you need to set the following property in your `application.properties` file.

```
camel.component.servlet.mapping.context-path= /*
```

Comment: Hi, sadly `http://192.168.0.100:8080/camel/api-doc` is still not working.

Comment: did you check overriding the context path and then hitting `http://192.168.0.100:8080/api-doc`

Comment: Ok, I inserted `camel.component.servlet.mapping.context-path= /*` in properties file. In web browser `http://192.168.0.100:8080/api-doc` is not giving result, but using curl to GET http://192.168.0.100:8080/api-doc is giving me 204 - No Content.

Comment: I would say that Swagger is now running, right? Can you give me some example how to add some content? Is it possible to setup Swagger UI the easy way (upgrading this)? I'm planning to set OAuth2 for Swagger in future, so I'm looking some easy way to do it and to test it.

Comment: `restConfiguration()
        .component("servlet").host("localhost").port(9292)
        .enableCORS(true)
        .apiContextPath("/api-doc")`

This is my rest configuration. And in my application.properties, I have `server.port =9292` and `camel.component.servlet.mapping.context-path= /*`.

It produces a nice looking api-doc!

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try it. I would like to use port 8080 for Swagger. In `application.properties` I have set server.port to 8081 because it's giving me an error trying run both netty-http and tomcat because of ports. I hope that this is not the reason of "empty" api-doc.

Comment: Which dependencies do you have in pom.xml?

Comment: But how to enable the ui and what would be the uri for that

Answer (score 0):

### For me adding the configuration :

### In routes

String listenAddress = "localhost";
int listenPort = 8003;

```
    restConfiguration()
            .component("servlet")
            .scheme("http")
            .host(listenAddress)
            .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto)
            .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true")
            .port(listenPort)
            .contextPath("/")
            // add swagger api-doc out of the box
            .apiContextPath("/api-doc")
            .apiProperty("api.title", "User API").apiProperty("api.version", "1.2.3")
            // and enable CORS
            .apiProperty("cors", "true");
```

---

### In application.properties

server.port=8003

### camel.component.servlet.mapping.context-path=/**

### URI

### http://localhost:8003/api-doc

I am using camel version : 3.9.0

---

This solution works fine !!!!